# Правильное использование глаголов

Tags: грамматика, глаголы

На днях появился до сих пор не решенный спор по поводу данного предложения.

**Увы, Сесилус не успел за ускользающим Мезореей, и на пределе прыжка потерял темп и упал обратно вниз.**

В данном контексте волнует конкретно отрезок *потерял темп и упал*.
Я лично вижу использование глагола "упал" как начало падения (после прыжка вверх на высокое расстояние), нежели уже как конечное приземление. Мой друг же говорит, что необходимо использовать глагол "падал", указывая на то, что объект (в данном случае Сесилус) уже находится на земле.

Я, к сожалению, не являюсь высшим грамотеем, хоть и чувствую, что вариант моего друга отвратителен (в частности, из-за того, что "падал" является глаголом несовершенного вида и вместе с глаголом "потерял" совершенного вида он никак не сочетается), но все-таки мне нужно доказательство со стороны: кто из нас прав?

Comment: Ну в предложении все глаголы совершенного вида, соответственно прошедшего времени. Предложение констатирует ситуацию в недалеком прошлом, что и характерно для повествований. То есть действие упал вниз уже произошло. Другое дело, что упасть вниз можно не упав на землю. Самолет упал вниз во время полета, но затем ему удалось снова набрать высоту. Но скорее прав ваш друг. Хотите сказать про начало падения - скажите про начало падения: "потерял темп и начал падать вниз"

Answer (score 2):

**Предлагается для обсуждения.**

*Увы, Сесилус не успел за ускользающим Мезореей, и на пределе прыжка потерял темп и упал обратно вниз.*

Предложение составлено некорректно с точки зрения семантики, **редактирование** как вариант:

*Увы, Сесилус **не успел** за ускользающим Мезореей: на пределе прыжка он **потерял темп** **и упал** обратно вниз.*

Конечный, существенный для повествования итог: **не успел.** А дальше описан процесс: **прыгал** вверх, но **потерял** скорость, поэтому **не достиг** цели и **упал**.

Тогда и **с запятой** будет ясно, а иначе ее трудно объяснить.

Comment: Да, запятая меня порадовала. При прочтении этого предложения впервые, захотелось разделить группы сказуемых.

Answer (score 1):

В данном случае глагол совершенного вида указывает на факт свершения действия, на его результат. Упал, потому что потерял темп.

Вообще глаголы совершенного вида указывают на завершенность действия, его конец или результат.
В данном предложении подчеркивается факт. Здесь нет необходимости использовать глагол несовершенного вида, который указывает на процесс, на продолжительность действия во времени. При этом надо учитывать и тот факт, что при использовании здесь глагола несовершенного вида нам не будет известно, упалo ли лицо( в данном случае  Сесилус) или нет.
Поэтому глагол СВ здесь вполне оправдан.